# Firefox Font Bleeding

Tags: firefox, browser, fonts, font-face

I'm using [Ostrich Sans Bold](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/ostrich-sans) for one of my headings. It renders nicely in every browser except Firefox (latest version).

Edit: Is there a way to have it render properly in Firefox? Or do I have to choose another style of typeface?

Here is an example (FF on top, chrome on bottom):

[image: Example].

I am using @font-face in my CSS.

Comment: There you go, made it a little neater. Note in the future that you can actually embed images, as I have done for you.

Comment: what file type(s) are you serving up in your @font-face?

Comment: @albert- eot, woff, ttf, svg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you perhaps not declaring this as a bold font in your @font-face rule, causing synthetic bolding to be applied?  Make sure the @font-face rule has `font-weight: bold` in it.

Also make sure that Firefox is not zoomed to a non-unit zoom on that page.

Past that, it's hard to say without seeing the actual site involved...

Comment: Sexy! How did you know to change the font-weight to bold, and how can I know in the future? I had no idea what to think since this was just in firefox.

Comment: I knew because I'd run into the problem before and your text looked synthetic-bold...  ;)  When the `@font-face` rule gives a font-weight, the font is assumed to be that weight.  If there is no explicit font-weight listed in the rule, then the font data is consulted.  Either way, if you have a font the browser thinks is normal weight but it's being asked to display bold text in it, then the browser ... does various things.  Some apply synthetic bolding; some just use a non-bold font for bold text directly. This can happen with a normal font without a bold face too, not just with `@font-face`.